# Design children layouts into a main GridLayout

Tags: python, pyqt4

I've did this tab:, I'm new to PyQt and QtLibs.

This is made with PyQt4:

```
class AddressBookTab(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super(AddressBookTab, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    grid.setSpacing(10)

    self.section1 = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.section2 = QtGui.QGridLayout()

    grid.addChildLayout(self.section1)
    grid.addChildLayout(self.section2)

    self.addrbook = QtGui.QTableWidget()
    self.addrbook.setColumnCount(4)
    self.addrbook.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['','Name', 'Address', ''])
    self.addrbook.setColumnWidth(1, 200)
    self.addrbook.setColumnWidth(2, 300)

    header = self.addrbook.horizontalHeader()
    header.setStretchLastSection(True)

    Name = QtGui.QLabel('Name')
    Address = QtGui.QLabel('Address')
    NameEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    AddressEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()

    self.section1.addWidget(self.addrbook, 0, 0)

    self.section2.addWidget(Name, 0, 0)
    self.section2.addWidget(NameEdit, 0, 1)
    self.section2.addWidget(Address, 1, 0)
    self.section2.addWidget(AddressEdit, 1, 1)

    self.setLayout(grid)
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
    self.show()
```

I have to build two separated sublayouts,

The first one on the top should load an addressbook table, which is already working.

The second tab, on the bottom, is an home for some tools related to the table: edit addressbook, do some actions with a couple of buttons, etc.

Probably I haven't understand how the childlayouts works, because the UI doesn't show them.

Any help to solve this issue and show the sublayouts, or any tip to do this in a better way, is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are your use method [`QLayout.addChildLayout (self, QLayout l)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlayout.html#addChildLayout) ? The only scenario in which you need to call it directly is if you implement a custom layout that supports nested layouts.

So, your use `QtGui.QGridLayout` it not unnecessary to call this method. Your should call [`QGridLayout.addLayout (self, QLayout, int row, int column, Qt.Alignment alignment = 0)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgridlayout.html#addLayout) it.

Example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class AddressBookTab (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(AddressBookTab, self).__init__()
        mainQGridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        mainQGridLayout.setSpacing(10)

        self.section1QGridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.section2QGridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        mainQGridLayout.addLayout(self.section1QGridLayout, 0, 0)
        mainQGridLayout.addLayout(self.section2QGridLayout, 1, 0)

        self.addrBookQTableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.addrBookQTableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        self.addrBookQTableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['','nameQLabel', 'addressQLabel', ''])
        self.addrBookQTableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 200)
        self.addrBookQTableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 300)

        headerQHeaderView = self.addrBookQTableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        headerQHeaderView.setStretchLastSection(True)

        nameQLabel           = QtGui.QLabel('nameQLabel')
        addressQLabel        = QtGui.QLabel('addressQLabel')
        nameEditQLineEdit    = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        addressEditQTextEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        self.section1QGridLayout.addWidget(self.addrBookQTableWidget, 0, 0)

        self.section2QGridLayout.addWidget(nameQLabel,           0, 0)
        self.section2QGridLayout.addWidget(nameEditQLineEdit,    0, 1)
        self.section2QGridLayout.addWidget(addressQLabel,        1, 0)
        self.section2QGridLayout.addWidget(addressEditQTextEdit, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(mainQGridLayout)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.show()

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myAddressBookTab = AddressBookTab()
myAddressBookTab.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my approach was wrong, your example works perfect and explained me how to handle this kind of design.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, combining two layout can be done by:

```
grid1 = QGridLayout()
grid2 = QGridLayout()
combined_grid = QGridLayout()
combined_grid.addLayout(grid1, 0, 0)
combined_grid.addLayout(grid, 1, 0)
```

this is applicable for all the layouts. In your case I would recommend `QVboxLayout()`, i.e. simply use:

```
vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addLayout(grid1)
vbox.addLayout(grid2)
```

in fact, you don't actually need your layout `self.section1` because it only contains one widget. To make it simpler, use：

```
vbox.addWidget(self.addressbook)
vbox.addLayout(self.section2)
```

And why it is not recommended to use `addChildLayout()` is just as what stated in its document -- "This function is called from addLayout() or insertLayout() functions in subclasses to add layout l as a sub-layout. The only scenario in which you need to call it directly is if you implement a custom layout that supports nested layouts." Same as the reason why use `addWidget()` instead of `addChildWidget()`